# Django/Bootrap Displaying Contacts from a Company

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have spent a few hours trying to solve this issue. Let me know if you have any ideas.
**Issue:** I have defined two models. One for Contacts and one for Company. I can create one contact and company separately. How can I display the contacts from one company. For example, if I`ve got contact1, contact2 working for CompanyA, I would like to be able to see them listed under the companyA profile.

Contacts

**models.py**

```
class Contact(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   company = models.ForeignKey(Company, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py**

```
def create_contact(request):
        form = ContactForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            contact = form.save(commit=False)
            contact.save()
            return render(request, 'contacts/detail.html', {'contact': contact})
        context = {
            "form": form,
        }
        return render(request, 'contacts/create_contact.html', context)
```

Company

**models.py**

```
class Company(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

**views.py**

```
def create_company(request):
    form = CompanyForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        company = form.save(commit=False)
        company.user = request.user
        company.company_logo = request.FILES['company_logo']            
        file_type = company.company_logo.url.split('.')[-1]           
        file_type = file_type.lower()          
        if file_type not in IMAGE_FILE_TYPES:
            context = {
                'company': company,
                'form': form,
                'error_message': 'Image file must be PNG, JPG, or JPEG',
            }
            return render(request, 'company/create_company.html', context)       
        company.save()
        return render(request, 'company/company_detail.html', {'company': company})
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, 'company/create_company.html', context)
```

**Company_detail.html**

```html
<table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            {% for contact in contacts.all %}               
        <tr>
            <td>{{ contact.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ contact.name }}</td>
            {% endfor %}    
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Below is the second views.py for contacts that I`ve created but does not solve it.

Contacts 2

**views.py**

```
def create_contact(request, company_id):
    form = ContactForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    company = get_object_or_404(Company, pk=company_id)
    if form.is_valid():
        companys_contacts = company.contact_set.all()
        for s in company_songs:
            if s.contact_title == form.cleaned_data.get("contact_title"):
                context = {
                    'company': company,
                    'form': form,
                    'error_message': 'You already added that contact',
                }
                return render(request, 'contacts/create_contact.html', context)
        contact = form.save(commit=False)
        contact.company = company
        contact.photo = request.FILES['photo']
        file_type = contact.photo.url.split('.')[-1]
        file_type = file_type.lower()
        if file_type not in IMAGE_FILE_TYPES:
            context = {
                'company': company,
                'form': form,
                'error_message': 'Image file must be PNG, JPG',
            }
            return render(request, 'contacts/create_contact.html', context)

        contact.save()
        return render(request, 'contacts/detail.html', {'company': company})
    context = {
        'company': company,
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'contacts/create_contact.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use company as a foreign key in your contacts model. That way, you can easily fecth contacts related to a company or you can also fetch company related to a contact

Comment: Thanks, I have added it as a foreignkey. What I am trying to find is how to display the loop. It should be something like {% for contact in company.contact_set.all %} and this is also the contact view that I`ve created.

Answer (score 0):

If the company obj is in the context, then you should be able to do:

```
{% for contact in company.contact_set.all %}               
  <tr>
    <td>{{ contact.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ contact.name }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

You can do something like `{{ company }}` to double check you are getting the company object correctly in the template.

Comment: Thanks, this works ok and I used this in my comment to the previous answer. The error that I have got is in my url and I got confused about this. I have got two apps: **contacts** and **company**. Each app had it is own url, for example: `url(r'^create_contact/$', views.create_contact, name='create_contact')`,. Now I am getting an error as my create contact looks like `{% url 'contacts:create_contact' company.id %}`. Can my company.id be in the contact app? My **urls.py** return an error when using `url(r'^(?P<company_id>[0-9]+)/create_contact/$', views.create_contact, name='create_contact'),`

Comment: The error message that I have got is:`Reverse for 'create_contact' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['contacts/(?P<company_id>[0-9]+)/create_contact/$']`